# Retrieve file path through browse input button

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I need to get the full file path including file name information to handle later with PHP.
I am running into many difficulties.

We can use a html form with the html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" />
```

However, to pass this information we need to the server, we actually have to upload the file, I do not want to do this as its wasteful, The reason being is that this project is just for my local machine, The file already exists on my machine.

A manual way of achieving this is to provide a input text field, and inserting the file(s) full location path here via another file navigation window(copy/paste), But this quickly becomes boring and requires to much work when using the tool often.

Any other suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: I would like to refer you to see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789934/browse-button-without-file-upload-in-html) answered by @jumpingcode

Comment: also have a look at these two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955603/php-browse-a-file-then-get-its-path

Comment: Well that certainly sucks, I guess I would have to deal with this completely out of a browser elsewhere.

Comment: This has nothing to do with complexity. You are trying to missuse the browser for something it is not designed for. You cannot blame the browser for that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. This has been discussed before and the explanations they give there are good, so I won't repeat:

[How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Answer (score -1):

paste following line under file tag,your problem will be solved
webkitdirectory directory multiple

```
<input type="file" id="ctrl" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
```

Comment: <input type="file" id="ctrl" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>