# Open input file in defined foder

Tags: html

I have an this input element :

```
<input type="file" />
```

What I need, is need for the explorer window to open in a specific path (eg. `C:/something/somthin_else`) when the user clicks the `Browse...` button.

This specific path may also be a user folder, like `My Documents` or `Downloads`.

is it even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browse button without file upload in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789934/browse-button-without-file-upload-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to security reasons, this is not possible.

A similar question was asked here

[Browse button without file upload in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789934/browse-button-without-file-upload-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. On the WWW you can't know what the directory structure of your visitors' systems are, and if you did and could then this would be a useful feature for attempts to trick users into uploading files they shouldn't. Browsers do not make it possible for a webpage to influence where a file browser will open by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible due to security reasons.

HTML and JavaScript are meant to interact on the client side. Selecting a directory involves the server side.

There is actually a very small hack if you're using Google Chrome

There is a new attribute for the `input[type=file]` attribute named `webkitdirectory`.

```
<input type="file" id="ctrl" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
```

It allows you to select directories. Use the `multiple` attribute for browsers that support multiple file selection but not directory selection.

However, it does block the selection of selecting individual files.

I stumbled upon this from a google search

https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/Dk5UhZ6zfF3

Do not use this as a solution to this problem. Like I said, it is a very small hack.